# Encrypting data into Postgres and decrypting from Postgres using sqlalchemy and ORM

Tags: python, postgresql, encryption, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

I want to encrypt data into Postgres and then decrypt and read from it. I prefer using sqlalchemy and ORM but if it is difficult to do using sqlalchemy and ORM then I am curious to know the other ways also

I tried using the below code, It is encrypting into the database but it is not asking me for any key or anything for the decryption. May I know why?

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from sqlalchemy_utils import EncryptedType
from sqlalchemy_utils.types.encrypted.encrypted_type import AesEngine

secret_key = 'secretkey1234'
connection_string = '***********'
engine = create_engine(connection_string)
connection = engine.connect()
sa.orm.configure_mappers()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=connection)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base()
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = sa.Column(EncryptedType(sa.Unicode,secret_key,AesEngine,'pkcs5'))
    number_of_accounts = sa.Column(EncryptedType(sa.Integer,secret_key,AesEngine,'oneandzeroes'))
Base.metadata.create_all(connection)
```

I run the below code for the decryption:

```
user_id = user.id
session.expunge_all()
user_instance = session.query(User).get(user_id)
print('username: {}'.format(user_instance.username))
```

Comment: "On the way in, the value is encrypted and on the way out the stored value is decrypted.", from https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#sqlalchemy_utils.types.encrypted.encrypted_type.EncryptedType. Could you please provide an example of a failure to decrypt? Have a look at how to produce a [mcve].

Comment: You can use the functions in the database extension `pgcrypto` if that is an option for you.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Thanks for the reply Ilja, actually I am able to read the encrypted data from the database but it is not asking me for any key or anything for the decryption. May I know why? I run the below code from the same link you provided:
user_id = user.id
session.expunge_all()
user_instance = session.query(User).get(user_id)
print('username: {}'.format(user_instance.username))

Also, I have added the decryption in my original question as well

Answer (score 1):

You have likely figured this out by now, as this question is a few years old, but for anyone else looking:

You are interacting with your Postgres tables through the model classes you define (in your example `User`).

When you execute a query, data is returned and passed through the class to determine how to process the response. From your example a query will return results for `id`, `username` and `number_of_accounts`. If you were to log each element returned, `id` would be processed as an `int` because that is how it is defined in your model.

Similarly, `username` and `number_of_accounts` will also be processed based on the definition in the `User` class - as an `EncryptedType()` value. This is a more complex datatype though. Your model defines the key to use for encryption/decryption. Prior to storing the value, the results are decrypted based on the context provided in your model. In this case using the `AESEngine` and decrypted with the key of `'secretkey1234'`. That is why you don't need to specify a key on read. It is already defined in your model.

If you were to run a `select * from user limit 1;` query directly on your Postgres db, the values displayed for your two encrypted columns would remain encrypted, as you would not be passing the results through your defined model.